# SQL doesn't allow to cast date column to datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

```
Select * 
from tableA 
inner join tableB on tableA.id = tableB.aid 
                  and cast(a.date AS DATETIME) = CAST('2015-08-24' AS DATETIME)
```

Values that stored in `tableA.date` are '2015-08-24' meaning data has no issue.

When I execute the above statement, I get

> The conversion of a date data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

May I know why cant cast a `date` column to `datetime`?

Comment: Are you certain ALL of the values in `a.date` are valid dates in an unambiguous format? (e.g. `1-2-2015` is ambiguous because it could be Jan 2nd of Feb 1st)

Comment: @D Stanley: It has one row data with value '0001-01-01', could this be the reason why it threw me that error?

Comment: what do you get if you run select max(a.date), min(a.date) from tableA a

Comment: @Mr.SuicideSheep of course, since `DATETIME` starts with January 1, 1753

Comment: @Mr.SuicideSheep Yes.  The minimum value for `DateTime` is '01-01-1753'

Comment: Meaning the problem solely coming from the data dirtiness and not syntax problem right? thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Try running this query and see invalid records.
`select * from tableA a  where isdate(a.date) =0`

Comment: Yep, use the IsDate function.......  and/or fix that row and then put a constraint on the table/column so it has to have a "real" date that is > 1753.

Comment: If you use IsDate do NOT make the mistake of thinking that you can short circuit the where predicates by putting IsDate first. You can't do that in sql server to ensure the order of operations. Ideally you should change the datatype of the table to datetime and stop storing this data as a string.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The **root cause** of the problem is this:

- the data type `DATE` has a range of accepted values from `01-01-0001` through `12-31-9999`
- the data type `DATETIME` has a range of accepted values from `01-01-1753` through `12-31-9999`

So if you happen to have a `DATE` from before 1753, or an empty / NULL value - this will be outside the range that `DATETIME` can handle.

You should *stop using* `DATETIME` In SQL Server **2008** and newer. Use `DATETIME2(n)` instead (where `n` stands for the number of fractional seconds you need).

So try this:

```
select * 
from tableA 
inner join tableB on tableA.id = tableB.aid 
                  and cast(a.date AS DATETIME2(3)) = CAST('2015-08-24' AS DATETIME2(3))
```

and I'm sure this'll work just fine.

Comment: Stop using *datetime* it is a difficult or not realistic solution if you are working  with CRM ERP and many others well known packages.
The common mistake is assuming that date is "smaller" than datetime. They are different I prefer to avoid problem filtering not castable values: *isnull(plain_date,'0001-01-01') > '1753-01-01'*

Comment: @DiegoScaravaggi: in terms of space needed - they **ARE** different - `DATE`  takes 3 bytes, while `DATETIME` takes 8 bytes (and covers a smaller range, too!)

Comment: sorry as "smaller" I meant that is a common mistake to suppose that DATE is just the YYYY-MM-DD part of DATETIME, and normally with 99.99% of crm erp data could be partially true. In my situation the bug was raised by a wrong etl from CSV, and we discovered that one column in DBMS was casted to DATETIME.
I'm very happy that you added this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use the format yyyymmdd which is universal in SQL Server,

```
Select * from tableA inner join tableB 
on tableA.id = tableB.aid 
and cast(a.date AS DATETIME) = CAST('20150824' AS DATETIME)
```

I did not see the problem with the '0001-01-01' value in `a.Date`. You could do a bit dirty trick like this:

```
Select * from tableA inner join tableB 
on tableA.id = tableB.aid 
and case when substring(a.date, 1, 2) not in ('19', '20') then null else CAST(a.date AS DATETIME) end = CAST('20150824' AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try incorporating ISDATE() just to make sure the data is valid.  (It sounds like tableA.date is a string.)

```
    Select * from tableA inner join tableB 
        on tableA.id = tableB.aid 
        and ISDATE(tableA.date)
        and cast(tableA.date AS DATETIME) = CAST('2015-08-24' AS DATETIME)
```