# DATEDIFF causing The conversion of a date data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

Why would the following SQL cause the error?

> SqlException: The conversion of a date data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I believe it has to do with the `DATEDIFF` and the type of DATE for `StartDate`?

```
(CASE WHEN @OrganizationId IS NOT NULL AND ev.EndDate >= @SortStartDate THEN 0
      WHEN ev.StartDate >= @SortStartDate THEN 1
      ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, ev.StartDate, -1) 
      END) ASC,
```

Comment: What data type is ev.StartDate? & what is an example of a failing value?

Comment: It is of type DATE but I cant tell you what the failing value is since this is in a SP and has many rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  The date on an event was set to `0209-06-01`.

Comment: I beg to differ, it was there in plain site.  This column used to be a DATETIME but was converted to DATE a while back.

Comment: Look it up buddy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568170/sql-doesnt-allow-to-cast-date-column-to-datetime

Comment: Not sure what variable you are referring to but DATEDIFF must convert the value to a DATETIME, not DATE